# Manually copy a PNG file using fgetc() and fputc() in C

Tags: c

I am trying to manually copy a PNG file by reading individual bytes (chars) from one file, and then using fputc() to place them into another file. This is essentially a proof of concept as the end goal is to deconstruct the file into a byte stream that can be sent to a socket and then the client on the other side can reconstruct the image. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("picture.PNG", "rb");
   fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // seek to beginning of file

   FILE *wfp;
   wfp = fopen("copy.PNG", "w");

   int c;
   while(TRUE){
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if (feof(fp)){
         break;
      }
      fputc(c, wfp);
   }

   fclose(wfp);
   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
   
}
```

The resulting PNG file *seems* to be a copy of the original in that it has the same/similar size and when opening it in notepad and comparing to the original they look the same. However, I can't open it as a PNG and see the original image, which is the whole point.

How do I fix this code or what is the right way to accomplish my goal? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need `fseek()`. Unless you open in append mode, you default to the beginning.

Comment: You need to open the output file in `wb` mode if you're running this on Windows.

Comment: "*opening it in notepad*". That is ok for a quick check but there are much better and precise ways. Use a diff tool for example so that you can get an exact answer and not "seems to" type statements.

Comment: @Barmar Wow. That was it. It works now. Adding one character to the code was all it took.

Comment: What confuses me is that you knew to do that when opening the file for reading. It's the same reason.

Comment: I didn't really understand why I needed the b for opening the reading file. I just saw it in a another question on here and copied it. I assumed you needed it for reading non-text files.

Comment: Don't use `feof`.  At best it will slow it down.  Just use `while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) fputc(c, wfp);`  That's all you need in the loop.

Comment: You also need the `b` for writing non-text files reliably.  On Unix-like systems, the presence or absence of `b` is immaterial; on Windows, it does matter.  All else apart, if you try to write `'\n'` to a text file, the I/O library will map that to `\r\n`, whereas it will leave a binary file with just `\n`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Chuckling, yes, while unnecessary, at least logically, they used `feof()` in the proper location instead of `while (feof(..)) { ... }`

Comment: Maybe you gain speed with fread() and fwrite() instead of fgetc/fputc.